# Convert from pointer to an object c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have got a problem with understanding the following code where I am trying to convert from the pointer to an object class Passenger* passenger to class Passenger passenger. I am not sure how I can modify my code to do perform the same functionality without the pointers. I am particularly confused with setting and comparing to NULL. Do I need to keep those if statements if I am no longer using the pointers? Any advises or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
class Seat
{
private:
    class Passenger* passenger;
public:
    Seat()
    {
        passenger = NULL;
    }

    ~Seat()
    {
        if (passenger)
        {
            delete passenger;
            passenger = NULL;
        }
    }

    bool insertSeat(class Passenger* p)
    {
        bool bsuccess = TRUE;
        if ( p != NULL )
        {
            if (passenger == NULL)
                passenger = p;
            else
                bsuccess = FALSE;
        }
        else
            passenger = NULL;
        return bsuccess;
    }

    bool outputSeat(int row,int seat)
    {
        if (passenger)
            cout << (passenger->toString()) << endl;
        else
            cout << "Empty " << row << seat+'A' << endl;
        return passenger != NULL;
    }
};
```

Comment: You need a way of indicating that a passenger has not been assigned to a seat.  Are you sure you want to do this?  it means that the seat owns the passenger.  OK if it is just an exercise but if it is for a project of some sort, you might want to rethink how you are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is :

```
class Seat
{
private:
    Passenger passenger;

public:
    Seat()
    { }

    void insertSeat( const Passenger& p ) // pass by const reference
    {
        passenger = p;
    }

    bool outputSeat( int row, int seat )
    {
        cout << passenger.toString() << endl;
    }
};
```

You can always implement checking; eg : you don't want an invalid or default constructed passenger when passing it to 
insertSeat() function :

```
    bool insertSeat( const Passenger& p ) // pass by const reference
    {
        if( /* p.empty() or p.invalid() or whatever*/ ) return false; // implement empty() method

        passenger = p;
        return true
    }
```